Road trip from Western to Eastern Europe (Balkan) with a rental car
I am planning a road trip starting in Paris, to Prague, Hungary, Serbia, Bosnia, Croatia and back to Paris.
Which rental car company can allow me to travel across all above countries?

What kind of research have you done yourself?

(+1) After the edit, the question is not asking for open-ended advice anymore but only about a single well-defined problem. It's also a difficult one, precise information on this is hard to come by and major brands usually would not cover Bosnia, maybe even Serbia and Hungary.

Can we assume you are planning to get some sort of midsize sedan or something like that? There are typically additional restrictions on high-end cars or convertibles.

@Relaxed I did a bit of searching and I found several sites listing allowed countries for various car rental companies, none of which included Bosnia. But the same brands will happily rent a car to you in Bosnia; they have offices in the Sarajevo airport. Restrictions depend on the country where you rent the car.  Obviously we know here that this car will be rented in France, but anyone else reading this for a similar reason with a different itinerary should understand that the restrictions may be different.  For example, if you rent from Sixt in Croatia, you can drive the car in Bosnia.

I am landing at Paris , but I can rent a car from different place as well like start the roadtrip at Munich . other option is - if Bosnia is not included in the list then skip Bosnia and enter from Serbia to Croatia (bigger circle).can you send me link to some car companies so that I can see the options and finalize the itinerary as I need to book hotels as well

@phoog Yes, definitely, I didn't spell it out but my previous comment was specifically about the French branches of major brands like Avis, Hertz, etc. And the official websites are sometimes vague on the restrictions (e.g. avis.fr).

I am looking for mid size sedan/suv economy car
